# Merge two option-objects with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge, extend

I plan to merge two objects that contain methods:

```
var options = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(1);
    }
}

var options2 = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(3);
    }
}

options = $.merge(options, options2);
```

But if I do `console.log(options.show)` I recieve only first array.

My question is, how to merge options array with options2?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As both function have the same name and also you have syntax error, it's not `cosole` but `console`

Comment: what is the desired result of your idea of merge ? However the $.merge function works with arrays, your options are objects. The result of the merge is the first object simply. If you add square brackets around your objects you will obtain an array containing the 2 objects. So the question is what is your requirement ? An array with the 2 objects ? Or something which prints the result of both show functions ? Or other ?

Comment: I'am trying to merge two console.log() in one show option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the oher function inside the first function block

```js
var options = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(1);
        options2.show();
    }
}

var options2 = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(3);
    }
}

options.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 'same property' name, they will override when you merge.
Use destructuring and rename and `Object.assign` should work.

```js
var options = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(1);
    }
}

var options2 = {
    show: function() {
        console.log(3);
    },
    other: () => console.log('other')
}

const { show: show2, ...rest2 } = options2;

Object.assign(options, { show2 }, rest2);

options.show();
options.show2();
options.other();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this

```js
var options = { show: function () { console.log(1); }, };
var options2 = { show: function () { console.log(3); }, };
res = Object.entries(options).map((o) => ({ [o[0]]: [o[1], options2[o[0]]] }));
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[0].show)
```